# How to create a SGE queue which can only be assigned jobs manually?

Tags: cluster, gridengine, grid

I have 5 nodes in an SGE cluster. I'd like to make it so one of those nodes can only be used by a specific queue, "test.q".

I can remove that node from hostlist on all of my other queues, and set hostlist to just that host in test.q.

However, when I do that, jobs where a specific queue isn't specified still sometimes end up in test.q.

How can I configure things so that test.q will only be assigned a job if someone *specifically* requests test.q?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just creating a queue which only one (test) user has permission for.